# export to image leaflet map with SVG markers in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, leaflet

I am building a javascript application (using angularjs) that uses [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) and [leaflet-dvf](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf) to display pie charts as SVG on a map. It is not using any server side languages (php, asp.net, etc), and I would like to keep it like this.

The application is now fully working and I would like to add the possibility to export the map with the SVG markers to png/pdf/whatever using javascript only. I have tried several solutions and I still did not find a suitable solution.

[Leaflet-Save-Map-to-PNG](https://github.com/tegansnyder/Leaflet-Save-Map-to-PNG) uses php and thus does not fit my needs.

[Leaflet.Print](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.print) requires geoserver or mapfish installed, I would like to use only javascript.

[Leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) does not render the SVG pies, only the base layer.

Did I miss any project or is there no solution for my problem?

Comment: An issue is opened at [Leaflet-image repo](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image/issues/13) to import custom markers, once it is resolved you may try for your pie charts.